# Google map autocomplete - maximum 3 character type

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, search-box

I have implemented Google map with search box in it which allows user to select address by searching it.

In that search box, even if I am typing 1 character it searches.. I want user to type at least 3 characters else it should not go for search.

```
My JS Fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/2NhsE/
```

How can I do this? Is Google provides that restriction?

Comment: Thanks whoever downvotes - it is not valid question!!!???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't provide this option for places autocomplete element at the moment.

There is a feature requests in the public issue tracker. Have a look at [issue 5831](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5831). The issue's status is Accepted, however there is no any ETA exposed. You can star this issue to add your vote and receive further updates.

Also there is a [comment #15](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5831#c15) with recommendation how to implement this using autocomplete service.

---

**Update: 04 June 2018**

This feature was marked as **Won't Fix (Obsolete)**

> This feature request is obsoleted by the new session-based billing for Places autocomplete. Please refer to the "Place Autocomplete" section of https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/ for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the string and rebuild the AutoComplete like this

in this case im using `jQuery` this API `stopImmediatePropagation` also about `val`

```
input.keyup(function(e){
if(input.val().length<2){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
}
else{
   createAutoComplete(input)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the autocomplete after user has entered at least minimum characters. Bellow code listens to keyup events on input with jQuery. When the user types 3rd character it will initialize the autocomplete.

I think your intension is to avoid additional API requests. This should work.

```
window.autocompleteobj =false;

//initialize map after 2 chars are typed
$('#autocompleteinput').keyup(function(e) {
    if ($('#autocompleteinput').val().length < 3) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    } else {
        if (window.autocompleteobj == false) {
            window.autocompleteobj = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autocompleteinput);
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteobj, 'place_changed', function() {
               //your stuff here
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of text input in pac-input textbox. if the length is greater than 3, then forward that query to google maps.

Comment: It is not allowing to check because it binds it internally.