# google-place-api autocomplete after typing 3 characters

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm using React.JS and I need to call google-place-api autocomplete after typing 3 characters in a search box. They have offset in their documentation but it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
renderAutoComplete() {
    let attr = this;
    const { google, map } = this.props;
    var autocompleParam = {
        offset: 4
    }
    const aref = this.refs.autocomplete;
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(aref);
    var start_location = document.getElementById('start_location')
    var from_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        start_location, autocompleParam, {
    });
    from_address.setComponentRestrictions({ 'country': ['uk'] });

    google.maps.event.addListener(from_address, 'place_changed', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('start_location').style.borderColor = '';
        var place = from_address.getPlace();
        attr.props.onChangeLocationSearch(place.place_id);
        attr.props.onGetLocationInfo(e);
    });

    var to_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('end_location')), {
    });

    to_address.setComponentRestrictions({ 'country': ['uk'] });

    google.maps.event.addListener(to_address, 'place_changed', function (e) {
        var place = to_address.getPlace();
        document.getElementById('end_location').style.borderColor = '';
        attr.props.onChangeEndLocationSearch(place.place_id);
        attr.props.onReturnLocation(e);
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks similar to previously answered question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64006859/1759519

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the 'to_address' value's length and then allow the .getPlace() call to take place. Something like this:

```
var autocompleParam = {
    offset: 3
}    

google.maps.event.addListener(to_address, 'place_changed', function (e) {
    if (to_address.value.length < autocompleParam.offset) {
        return;
    }
    var place = to_address.getPlace();
    document.getElementById('end_location').style.borderColor = '';
    attr.props.onChangeEndLocationSearch(place.place_id);
    attr.props.onReturnLocation(e);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this and this don't work. My concern is to reduce google place autocomplete api call for typing each charecter